# netlify form submission not showing file on the back end, all other fields are showing up but not the file upload

Tags: netlify

Even though it is mostly from the netlify site, I can't seem to figure out why the file upload doesn't work. What I get on the other end is all the fields, but the file upload comes back blank with no error in the console. Looked at videos and online instructions and don't see what the difference is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Contact</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- A little help for the Netlify post-processing bots -->
    <form name="contact" netlify   hidden>
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <input type="text" name="CompanyName" />
      <input type="text" name="Address" />
      <input type="text" name="PrimaryContact" />
      <input type="text" name="SecondaryContact" />
      <input type="email" name="email" />
      <textarea name="message"></textarea>
      <input  type="file" name="myFile"/>
    </form>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">

      const encode = (data) => {
        return Object.keys(data)
            .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
            .join("&");
      }

      class ContactForm extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = { name: "",CompanyName:"",Address:"",PrimaryContact:"", SecondaryContact:"", email: "", message: "" , myFile:""};
        }

        /* Here’s the juicy bit for posting the form submission */

        handleSubmit = e => {
          fetch("/", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
            body: encode({ "form-name": "contact", ...this.state })
          })
            .then(() => alert("Success!"))
            .catch(error => alert(error));

          e.preventDefault();
        };

        handleChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

        render() {
          const { name,CompanyName, Address, PrimaryContact,SecondaryContact,email, message,myFile } = this.state;
          return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} data-netlify-recaptcha="true" data-netlify="true">
              <p>
                <label>
                  Your Name: <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={this.handleChange} required/>
                </label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <label>
                  Company Name: <input type="text" name="CompanyName" value={CompanyName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <label>
                  Address: <input type="text" name="Address" value={Address} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <label>
                  Primary Contact: <input type="text" name="PrimaryContact" value={PrimaryContact} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <label>
                  Secondary Contact: <input type="text" name="SecondaryContact" value={SecondaryContact} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <label>
                  Your Email: <input type="email" name="email" value={email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <label>
                  Ticket Discription: <textarea name="message" value={message} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
              </p>
              <p>
                    <input  type="file" name="myFile"  placeholder="Upload File" />
              </p>
              <p>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
              </p>
            </form>
          );
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(<ContactForm />, document.getElementById("root"));

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I too have a similar issue. I have updated the content-type to be multipart/form-data but I still see a blank field for my file uploads. I do have multiple files being uploaded in one form but it is still 1 file per field. I think it has something to do with the encode function. Did you work out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and was able to solve it using this checklist from the Netlify community:

> *6. Make sure that you POST your form request (not GET) with a Content-Type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded in most cases. However, **if and only if you are submitting the form with a file upload then the Content-Type needs to be multipart/form-data instead**.*
>
> from: [[Common Issue] Form problems, form debugging, 404 when submitting](https://community.netlify.com/t/common-issue-form-problems-form-debugging-404-when-submitting/92)

Moving to a different `Content-Type` solved a similar issue for me. Then again I'm not using fancy Javascript/Ajax form submission so all it took was to add an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to my form tag. In your case it will require reworking your `encode` function.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue.

Removing the **headers** option from the **fetch()** function did it for me.

Ex:

```
fetch("/", {
  method: "POST",
  // headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
  body: encode({ "form-name": "contact", ...this.state })
})
```